# Controller not returning view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have two controllers - Login and List

I am validating the credentials and returning the list view.

LoginController.cs

```
public ActionResult Authentication(string GlobalId, string password)
{
    // validation code
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "List");
}
```

ListController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<EbitProjectModel> obj = new List<EbitProjectModel>();
    obj = _categoryMasterService.getProjectInformationAll();
    return view("Index", obj);
}
```

Here its redirecting correctly to Index method of ListController. But its not rendering that view (Index view). It's keeping the same view (Login view) from which i called Authentication method with the help of ajax.BeginForm post.

Is there anything i am missing here?

Comment: Just use return view(obj); in List controller

Comment: This doesn't look like actual code - the action-redirect points to a projectlist-controller rather than a list-controller, the view-method in the list-controller is misspelled (lowercase v). What happens when you debug? Does execution step into the list-controller's index-action?

Comment: @J.Steen My bad.. i have edited the code . its pointing to correct Controller. .. yes after debug.. Its stepping into the list controllers action method... code is getting executed but not returning view

Comment: How are you calling the `Authentication` route? Could AJAX be involved? You mentioned an Html.BeginForm is used to submit the credentials but could there be some javascript which is AJAXifying this form and making a partial callback instead of full postback? Looking at the browser console should provide you with answers to those questions.

Comment: @BalajiM .. tried that .. still no luck

Comment: @DarinDimitrov .. yes im using Ajax.BeginForm to call that action method

Comment: OK, that explains it all :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, contrary to what has been initially stated in your question, you are using `Ajax.BeginForm` instead of an `Html.BeginForm`. The difference is that the first will submit the form using an AJAX request. This means that the browser will not navigate away from the page and it is then your responsibility to update the DOM with whatever information comes from this AJAX request.

In this case it makes no sense to return a `View` from such an action but rather a `PartialView` so that you could update only the relevant portion of your DOM:

```
return PartialView("Index", model);
```

And in order for this *update* to happen you need to indicate in your `Ajax.BeginForm` the id of a div where the result will be injected:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
{
    ...
}
```

which assumes that you have the following placeholder:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

But since this is a login form it probably makes more sense to do a full postback and navigate away from the Login form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...
}
```

In this case the browser will POST the credentials to the `Authentication` action which in turn will redirect to the `Index` action of your ListController and render the corresponding view.

Comment: yes .. you are right.. i made a silly mistake by using Ajax.BeginForm here... its working well with heml.Beginform .. thanks